# How to find which app scripts are running?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet on which I have applied immediate notification on any changes. From few days I am continuously receiving notification of changes 3 to 4 times an hour with the following message:

```
  See the changes in the Google Document "Paper-Teacher Database": 
  Click here
  A user made changes from 5/23/18 5:39 AM to 5:28 AM (Pacific Daylight 
  Time)
```

Also the mails are at fairly regular interval, for example I received mail at
6:09 PM, 7:44 PM, 7:59PM, 8:20PM, 8:44PM, 8:58PM, 9:20PM, 9:28PM, 9:58PM, 10:20PM. 10:28PM

Since the user name is not specified, I believe the changes are being made at the owners end (thats me). Also since I am manually not making any changes, I believe some script is doing it. To the best of my knowledge I do not have any script which is time triggered 3-4 times an hour.

Is there a way to find out the erroneous script and stop it?

Answer (score 2):

While signed in go to https://script.google.com/ Open the hamburger menu in the upper left corner and select “My executions” to see the list of the recently executed functions and associated projects.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I checked the scripts under my executions and found that no script is running at interval less than one hour. Still I am getting notifications several times in an hour.